# An entity with the same identity already exists in this EntitySet. - WCF RIA Services

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have the following code that I would expect would check to see if an entity exists and, if not, add it to the collection. I then call submit changes on the context to save the changes.

```
int kwID = (int)(from d in this._keywordSource.Source where d.keyword.ToLower() == searchText.ToLower() select d.keywordID).FirstOrDefault();
if ( null == this._context.Rules.Where(e => e.keywordID == kwID && e.searchTerm == item.SearchTerm).FirstOrDefault())
    {
        this._context.Rules.Add(new Rule() { keywordID = kwID, searchTerm = item.SearchTerm, processed = false });
    }
```

I am testing this with 3 keywords/searchTerm combos:

Apple/Apple

iPad/iPad

iPod/iPod

The first attempt never runs the .Add line of code. The second does, successfully. The third throws the error `An entity with the same identity already exists in this EntitySet.`.

I've read that this has something to do with the identity & seed, especially if your seed is 0 in the db. Mine isn't (set to 1). The EntitySet itself has ~1900 items in it.

What am I missing here?

[EDIT]
Added the kwID code to show that keyword is ultimately the kwID in the conditional.

The primaryKey of this table is ruleID. This is what I believe is being violated in the error message.... but I don't know how or why.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, wrong condition.
Example:
U've got in your DataBase:

- KWid: 5, SearchTerm: iPod
- KWid: 6, SearchTerm: iPad

And in your condition u put values

- KWid: 5, SearchTearm: GooglePhone

`this._context.Rules.Where(e => e.keywordID == 5 && e.searchTerm == "GooglePhone").FirstOrDefault()` returns null and so u try to add a row with existing KWid.

Solution: Change && condition to ||

```
if ( null == this._context.Rules.Where(e => e.keywordID == kwID || e.searchTerm == item.SearchTerm).FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: I prob should have put in my code block that the keyword gets resolved to a kwID. Updating now to reflect. Sorry. There CAN be multiple searchTerms for a specific kwID

Comment: Ok. Have u noticed the RuleId for iPad/iPad entity?

Comment: oddly enough they're already in my database, so I don't know why this is firing the way it is. I'm rather new to EF...